# Equivalent of UseMvc AllowAnonymous with endpoint routing (UseEndpoints) in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

What is the .Net Core 3.1 equivalent of the following when using Endpoint Routing in .Net Core 3.1?

```cs
protected override void ConfigureTestServices(IServiceCollection services) 
    => services.AddMvc(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
```

In .Net Core 2.2, I had `Startup` as follows:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ... 
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In my tests, in .Net Core 2.2, I would have:

```cs
protected void ConfigureTestServices(IServiceCollection services)
    => services.AddMvcCore(x => x.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
```

In .Net Core 3.1, I have...

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ... 
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks((builder) =>
            builder.WithMetadata(new AllowAnonymousAttribute()));
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

How do I allow all my tests to run without authorization, as I used to be able to in .Net Core 2.2? (Note, in production, I want authorization against the controller endpoints; and to allow anonymous access to the controller endpoints during testing)

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddMvc(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
```

The “modern” equivalent for this in ASP.NET Core 3.x and later would be the following:

```
services.AddControllers(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
```

Alternatively, you can also use `AddRazorPages()` or `AddControllersWithViews()` depending on how you have your application set up.

But `AddMvc` is actually still supported and just literally means the combination of both `AddRazorPages()` and `AddControllersWithViews()`. Similarly, `AddMvcCore` is also still around and is actually called by all those other `Add~` methods.

So you can really do any of the following and they mostly do the same thing:

```
services.AddMvc(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
services.AddMvcCore(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
services.AddControllers(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
services.AddControllersWithViews(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
services.AddRazorPages(opt => opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter()));
```

---

Note that this does not really have to do anything with endpoint routing though. The move from `AddMvc` to `AddControllers`, `AddControllersWithViews` and `AddRazorPages` was just a way to further split up the underlying framework dependencies so you only pay for those dependencies that you actually need to run your application. E.g. if you only have API controllers, then you don’t need the Razor engine and can opt-out by only calling `AddControllers()`.

Endpoint routing on the other hand is what the move from `UseMvc` to `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`. This applies to how the middleware pipeline works though, not how the dependencies are set up. For the purpose of registering global MVC filters, you can still configure these globally by configuring the `MvcOptions` with one of the `Add~` calls from above.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had tried setting `opt.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter())`, with no luck before asking the question. Perhaps I didn't clearly describe the issue I was facing (although I tried)- I resolved the issue using `services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, FakePolicyEvaluator>();` and then implementing `FakePolicyEvaluator`, such that I can make unauthorized requests to the endpoints.